# Getting started at tradingview and referencing balances

Tags: reference, pine-script

I may be new to tradingview but their pinescript programming language seems to be the best I've ever seen for automated trading. They seem to really want me to succeed but I cannot find where it tells me how to access the balances for certain balances. I am trying to make a code where I do not reinvest the extra I make so I have to be able to reference the available amount. I have not quite finished the manual yet but I do not see what variable or function allows me to do that, or at least not where I would expect it.

Comment: Well, is there a variable I can pull that references how much in one asset or another is of the total equity?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`strategy.equity`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dequity). There are quite a few built-in variables for strategy values. You can inspect them from the refman by searching on "strategy".

You can also calculate your own metrics using a technique like [this](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-calculate-custom-statistics-in-a-strategy) one if you don't find what you need in the built-ins.

And welcome to Pine! This is the best place to start your journey:
https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000561836